# Why is my test Java method only returning the first key in my list?

Tags: java

```
    public Key equalorLess(Key key) {
    if (first == null || first.key.compareTo(key) > 0) return null;
    Node x = first;
    while(x.next != null && x.next.key.compareTo(key) <= 0) {
        x = x.next;
    }
        return x.key;
  }
```

This is code to return a the largest key in a table that is < or = to inputted key. So in "abcd" if you call "e" you'll return "d". Or if you called "a" you'd get "a".

I'm writing test code that looks like the following. Precursor, I know its a mess.

```
        public static void equalorLessTest( String key, String answer) {
        String keys = "abcdefijklxyz";
        LinkedList<String,Integer> newLst= new LinkedList<String,Integer>();
        for (int i =0; i < keys.length(); i++) {
        newLst.put(keys.substring(i, i+1),i);
        }
        String result = newLst.equalorLessTest(key);
        if ( answer == null) {
            if (result == null)
                StdOut.format("equalorLessTest: Correct  String %s Answer: null\n", key,result);
            else
                StdOut.format("equalorLessTest: *Error*  String %s Actual: %s\n", key,result);
            return;
        }
        if (result == null && answer != null ) { 
            StdOut.format("equalorLess: *Error*  String %s Actual: null\n", key,result);
            return;
        }
        if ( result.compareTo(answer) ==0)  
            StdOut.format("equalorLess: Correct  String %s Actual: %s\n", key,result);
        else
            StdOut.format("equalorLess: *Error*  String %s Actual: %s\n", key,result);
    }
```

The only test that works is checking for null. I'm iterating over that test set of keys. So, if I call "b" as my input, I get "a". Every single one I try to test returns "a". And in other test cases, I tend to get nulls or the first key in the given list I create. Can somebody please look at my test method and tell me what's going on. I believe the actual function is right. And it needs to be done in this manner. I can't use alternate methods.

Comment: Welcome! Please note that this site is not a debugging service. Copy-pasting large slabs of code into the question and asking us to debug it is off-topic. However, we can help you with *specific* questions about small *parts* of your code (a few lines), ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to narrow its focus and remove all code not directly relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Both branches of the `if` are the same:

```
if(temp!= null && x.key.compareTo(temp) >= 0) 
    temp = x.key;
else
    temp = x.key;
```

That’s got to be a bug.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to fix it where the code will do what it's supposed to....I'm still lost, but I now see the bug. Basically, I want to find the largest key that is = or < the given one. So "abcdy" is your list, client asks for "b" and gets "b". But if he asks for "z" it is not there so it gets the next largest one.

Comment: I edited and altered the code in a different way but still isn't working. Do you mind taking another look?

Comment: @billybob your question is now a different question, so you should revert the edit and ask a new one. However, as an observation, I would have thought returning the Node would have been more useful than returning the key. I’m not going to debug your code for you.